# PostgreSQL: Squelize to raw query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to convert the following `Sequelize` into raw `PostgreSQL` query:

```
db.User.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 10003
    },
    include: [{
        model: db.Diet,
        required: false,
        as: 'diets', // an array
    }, {
        model: db.Spice,
        required: false,
        as: 'spice_level',
    }]
}).then((user) => { ... }
```

Here is the raw query:

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_diet_table;
CREATE
TEMPORARY TABLE temp_diet_table ON
COMMIT
DROP AS
SELECT d.id,
       d.name,
       d.desc,
       d.type,
       d."createdAt",
       d."updatedAt",
       d.status,
       d.user_id
FROM diet d
WHERE d.user_id = 10003;

  (SELECT json_build_object ('id', u.ID, 'username', u.username, 'first_name', u.first_name, 'last_name', u.last_name, 'createdAt', u."createdAt", 'updatedAt', u."updatedAt", 'spice_level', json_build_object ('id', sp.ID, 'level', sp.LEVEL, 'updatedAt', sp."updatedAt", 'createdAt', sp."createdAt"), 'color', A.color, 'diets', COALESCE (
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   (SELECT json_agg (json_build_object ('id', d.ID, 'name', d.NAME, 'desc', d.DESC, 'type', d.TYPE, 'createdAt', d."createdAt", 'updatedAt', d."updatedAt", 'status', d.status))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    FROM temp_diet_guest_table d
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    WHERE d.user_id = u.ID ), json_build_array ()))
   FROM "user" u
   INNER JOIN app_common A ON A.owner_id = u. ID
   LEFT JOIN Spice sp ON sp.owner_id = u.ID
   WHERE u.ID = r.user_id ))));  COMMIT;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
, Time: 0.082000s
```

I am new to `PostgreSQL` raw queries.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not *a* query, that's multiple statements. Does Postgres support the [`multipleStatements` option](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries) on connection? Could you run each statement individually instead?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I have similar queries that are currently working.

Comment: Are you sure each part runs correctly? That statement could have a syntax error. You could try replacing the long, complex query with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT 1` or something extremely minimal.

Comment: Since there is a `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.  What's a good way to test each one?

Comment: I'd use the `psql` command-line, but anything similar works fine. You want to verify each component is valid before integrating them all into this monster.

Comment: I removed `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` and tried just to `WHERE d.user_id = 10003;` I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I have a feeling something's wrong in that query, but it's not obvious here, mostly due to how it's necessary to scroll horizontally to see the whole thing. Make sure the syntax is valid.